# Why do we define such a thing as singularity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

According to general relativity, an observer not in the close proximity of a black hole, observing a mass fall into that black hole, will never see that mass cross event horizon(it will gradually fade but never actually pass through the event horizon) as it requires an infinite amount of time to do so. So, effectively, for the observer, the mass of the object falling in will never reach the middle of the event horizon, or the so called "singularity", as it will require more-than-infinite amount of time to do so.

Then why do we even define such a thing as a singularity?

I am alright with the singularities in space-time curvature, but not with a finite amount of mass being compressed into zero volume, not because it is silly, because it would never happen in a finite time for a casual observer outside of black hole.

Comment: I am not sure what the actual question is. We don't define any singularity but rather just notice that it is a consequence of the GTR. As for what happens under the horizon: no external observer will ever observe it, so you can ignore singularities if you want (most people would ignore black holes completely anyway, if it wasn't for Star Trek). Nevertheless, it's interesting to ask what your theory tells about the situations you can't yet observe (i.e. you extrapolate the theory).

Comment: BTW, the singularity is not in the "middle" of the event horizon. An observer who passes through the horizon does not find the singularity at some particular spatial location, rather it is in their future. That's why they can't avoid it. It's like death and taxes.

Comment: Yes, yes, I have grown much more knowledgeable about the issue of singularity since I asked the question. Thank you for your concern Jeff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the distant observer will never observe the infalling observer crossing the event horizon, the infalling observer will intersect the horizon in a finite, calculable amount of local time.  So, understanding the singularity is important for understanding the fate of that observer, certainly.

Second, if you believe that Hawking radiation is real, then the picture isn't quite so stark--the radius of the black hole will decrease, and it will be possible to see some of the collapsing matter at late times.  Understanding the singularity is critical to understanding what exactly happens when the radius of the black hole becomes very small (say, a radius of one planck length).

Third, in addition to black hole singularities, you have big bang singularities, which are also a consequence of a general theorem in relativity.  Understanding what happens near the big bang singularity (or what quantum effects may cause the singularity not to happen, and perhaps trigger something like inflation) is one of the central questions in cosmology.

Comment: "While the distant observer will never observe the infalling observer crossing the event horizon, the infalling observer will intersect the horizon in a finite, calculable amount of local time." - yes. "So, understanding the singularity is important for understanding the fate of that observer, certainly." - no. Because the time of life of any BH is finite also, and shorter than the time untill the infalling observer will intersect the horizon.

Comment: @Anixx: No.  The lifetime of a black hole cannot even be accurately calculated by current theory, but all estimates for realistic astrophysical black holes say that the lifetime of the hole is very long (millions of years), while the GR calculation for the lifetime of the observer before they intersect the singularity is very, very short (less than a second for radial infall).

Comment: In different reference frames, millions of years for distant observer=seconds for the free falling. You just confuse them. For free falling observer the BH also will evaporate in seconds.

Comment: @Anixx: show me the calculation, or give me an argument as to why you believe this to be the case.  Because as far as I know, no one even knows for sure if the end point of the black hole's life is total evaporation, so your argument is speculative at best.  Also, if its life was seconds, it would still be far longer than the time for an observer to fall in from the horizon to the singularity.

Comment: The time for an observer to reach the event horizon is infinite by the clock of external observer. The time for the BH to evaporate is finite. For an infalling observer the exact time may be different but the sequence of the events is the same: the BH evaporates before he reaches the event horizon.

Comment: @Anixx: That argument is heuristic at best, and is overtly false in the case of a Vaiyda spacetime (which describes one particular way to have a shrinking black hole) with a decreasing mass function.

Comment: And this is well known, by the way. The only sources that claim one can move under the even horizon and reach singularity are either 40-50 years old or just do not account for quantum and thermodynamic effects and consider purely geometrical features of the GR solutions.

Comment: Other principles that prohibit one from moving under the event horizon are: holoraphic principle (all information is on the surface), no-hair theorem (BH has no internal structure) information loss paradox (all information about infalling objects should be radiated back), cosmic censorship (there are no singularities in the physical space), speed of light limit (an object under the horizon would move faster than light) etc.

Comment: @Anixx: seriously, you need to provide a reference or something more than a popular-level justification of this claim.  I even gave you an actual, concrete model to talk about.  Also, there is no event horizon in a spacetime where the black hole evaporates.  The apparent horizon fails to even be a dynamical horizon.  Also, cosmic censorship is unproven, and there are exact solutions that show it to be false (it is believed that solutions satisfying CC are a dense set in the configuration space, though).

Comment: "and there are exact solutions that show it to be false" - solutions of what? of course no theory that accounts for quantum effects can permit singularities, this is contrary to the basic principles of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Anixx: Exact solutions of einstein's equation that describe evaoporating black holes where there are timelike geodesics that intersect the singularity before the black hole evaporates.  No one can say anything about singularity resolution, other than it is expected to happen (NOT that it is known to happen) in a theory of quantum gravity, since there is no theory of quantum gravity.  Your heuristic about the quick evaporation time is explicitly false at the classical level, even when incorporating evaporation effects (though, of course, the exact form of these is unknown).

Comment: "Exact solutions of einstein's equation" OK. but this equation is for a stationary BH. Which lives forever. This is unlike real black holes, which evaporate.

Comment: "Your heuristic about the quick evaporation time is explicitly false at the classical level" - ?? I did not understand this sentence.

Comment: @Anixx:  No, there are solutions that don't involve staticity.  All that you need is a finite evaporation time, and a timelike singularity.  A charged Vaidya solution is all that you need, and it is explicitly not static.

Comment: You gave a heuristic argument for why an observer couldn't fall into the singularity based around redshifts.  Classically, this heuristic argument is false, even if you take evaporation effects into account.

Comment: I did not say anything about redshifts. The fact that by the time of the external observer the infalling observer will never reach the horizon is well known. This fact can be derived by different means.

Comment: @Anixx: THEN SHOW ME ONE.  JUST ONE.  You are saying wrong things left and right, and you are confusing apparent and event horizons all through this discussion.  A contracting horizon will form a timelike surface in the spacetime.  A timelike surface is very definitely transversible.

Comment: "you are confusing apparent and event horizons" - It is you who uses some strange terminology. You claim that "there is no event horizon in a spacetime where the black hole evaporates" - this is contrary to the accepted terminology, usually event horizon is perceived as pre-requisite for Hawking radiation. There is no Hawking radiation without event horizon (although pre-Hawking radiation can precede it).

Comment: @Anixx: Nope.  Look up "Event Horizon" in Hawking and Ellis or in Wald or whatever, and you will see that the definition is "the boundary of the past development of future null infinity.  If there is no singularity at late times, then this is the empty set.  You mean apparent horizon in everything that you're saying.

Comment: No, event horizon is the boundary of a black hole by definition. If there is no event horizon, then there is no black hole. And no Hawking radiation.

Comment: @Anixx: NO.  PLEASE READ ANY REFERENCE.  REALLY, ANY REFERENCE.  I REFERRED YOU TO TWO VERY STANDARD ONES. Don't talk like an expert if you don't understand basic terminology.

Comment: seriously, this is universally agreed upon terminology, and has been since the early '70s.  Pick up any relativity textbook.

Comment: "the boundary of the past development of future null infinity" - this is only true for static eternal black holes. "seriously, this is universally agreed upon terminology, and has been since the early '70s." indeed apparently you're operating with very old terminology.

Comment: "Your heuristic about the quick evaporation time is explicitly false at the classical level" - on what this claim is based?

Comment: By the way, the apparent Hawking temperature and radiation density rises for an infalling observer: $T=\frac{T_H}{\sqrt{1-\frac{r_S}{r}}}$ where r is the distance from the center of the BH. As the observer approaches the horizon, the energy density becomes infinite. This means that the observer sees the BH to finally explode.

Comment: @Anixx:  I'm done talking to you until you cite some sort of reference.  You repeatedly say wrong things, then cite popular level crap at me, contradicting basic definitions for no apparent reason.  I cite back basic, standard texts on General Relativity, and you refuse to make any conterarguments.  Cite some actual physics or just say that you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: I already named you multiple principles which prohibit moving under the event horizon. I hope you can find information about them in Google yourself as well as on the paradoxes that arise. These are such fundamental principles that it is not so important how precisely that or this lifetime, evaporation, speed derived. "You repeatedly say wrong things" - no, I do not. It is you who cites 30-years old textbooks on GR as if they contained some ethernal truth.

Comment: @Anixx: You named principles, and I told you why what you were saying about them was invalid.  You have yet to actually do a calculation or explain why your supposed results are valid. You don't even know what an event horizon is (and yes, the definition was made even more than 30 years ago, and is still used in the literature in almost every recent paper).   Math doesn't change.  The results I cite haven't changed.  Drop this popular-level crap and give me some sort of technical result that corroborates anything that you're saying.  You can't, because your claims are wrong.

Comment: While we're at it, give me a single technical source, ANYWHERE, that is consistent with your claim of what an event horizon is.  It is the boundary of the past development of future null infinity.  That is the definition.  That is what researchers define an event horizon as.  And it is the null set for a spacetime containing a black hole that evaporates in a finite amount of time.

Comment: "You named principles, and I told you why what you were saying about them was invalid." - where? " The results I cite haven't changed." - you claimed that the BH will exist forever. This maybe not changed, but only in a purely geometric theory.

Comment: "It is the boundary of the past development of future null infinity." - by the way, this is correct even for radiating BH. Why do you claim that with Hawking radiation such surface does not exist?

Comment: "You have yet to actually do a calculation or explain why your supposed results are valid." - no it is you who should show that your absurd claim that two observers will end up seing different events happening is valid.

Comment: @Anixx: Nowhere do I claim that Hawking radiation does not exist or that the black hole is eternal.  What I do claim is that a spacetime with an evaporating black hole has no event horizon.  It has an apparent horizon, but not an event horizon.  That is my point.  I also claim that if the singularity is timelike, even if the hole eventually evaporates, you can have timelike geodesics that intersect the singularity before the black hole evaporates.  These are both just basic facts.  And I really am done talking to you unless you can cite a paper or do a calculation.

Comment: @Anixx: and while I don't claim that the black hole is eternal, I do claim that the end part of the evaporation process is very, very poorly understood right now--Hawking radiation is derived through semiclassical reasoning, and when the back-reaction of the radiation is large compared with the black hole, or when the hole has a temperature approaching Planck temperature, all bets are off as to what will happen.

Comment: "What I do claim is that a spacetime with an evaporating black hole has no event horizon." - then there is no BH. Event horizon is the defining feature of BH. "even if the hole eventually evaporates, you can have timelike geodesics that intersect the singularity before the black hole evaporates" - surely. The problem is they are purely geometric objects. Having geodesics does not imply that something made of matter can follow them.

Comment: "I do claim that the end part of the evaporation process is very, very poorly understood right now" - may be and what? We did not discuss the final stages of BH. To conclude that the infalling observer will never cross the horizon one only need to know that the BH exists finite time.

Comment: @Anixx: we're done.  Learn some general relativity.  As in, do calculations with it.  And please look up the difference between an apparent horizon and an event horizon.  You are meaning 'apparent horizon' but saying 'event horizon'.  Bye.

Comment: Any black hole, evaporating or not have both. For a spherical BH they coincide. So what the point of insisting that evaporating BH has no event horizon? What a definition of BH then?

Comment: It seems that you believe that once a BH evaporates, the matter which is under the horizon is released. This is not true.

Comment: @Anixx: we're done.  You're not interested in listening to what I have to say, and you refuse to provide either a concrete calculation corroborating your claims, or a link to someone who does such a calculation.